# can't stop pedaling or chain drops down

Tags: chain, gears, pedals

Managed to unstick derailer. But can't stop pedaling or chain drops down.So when trying to stop bike. have to take feet off pedal to not catch chain

Comment: Sounds like your freewheel mechanism is stuck or broken. If you lift the bike off the ground and hold the cogs in the rear in place, can you spin the rear wheel? Some freewheel mechanisms can be opened and serviced.

Comment: No i can't spin it

Comment: If the derailleur was stuck as well, I'm guessing the bike is rather neglected.  It might be wise to get it thoroughly serviced

Comment: I have only had the bike for about 3 to 4 months. It started happening after it got heavily rained on last week. So i am thinking its stuck. Cause it unsticks from time to time. then catches again.